# SSDs in RAID slower than single device/tips to improve performance

Tags: raid, btrfs, ssd

I have a couple of hosted servers, running Debian 7, one has a single Samsung MZ7LM120HCFD, the other has 3 Intel SSDSC2BB160G4 in RAID1. The machine with the single Samsung SSD has significantly faster random file access with thousands of small files, which I depend on a lot, but I couldn't sleep at night, knowing I had no redundancy.

Now, the SSDs are different, and I can't do anything about that, but shouldn't having 3 drives to read from compensate for that?

Which leads me to; what can I do to improve it? Some mdadm magic or would changing from ext4 to btrfs or xfs help me out?

The workload is about 80% reads and 20% writes.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
md1 : active raid1 sdc1[2] sdb1[1] sda1[0]
    20478912 blocks [3/3] [UUU]

md2 : active raid1 sdc2[2] sdb2[1] sda2[0]
    135282624 blocks [3/3] [UUU]
    bitmap: 1/2 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: 3 disks in raid 1? Are you using one of them as "hot-spare", cause raid1 setups rely on a even number of disks...

Comment: Are these reads or writes? Writes are going to be slower, it's got to go to more devices.

Comment: @nwildner No they don't. RAID1 creates *n* copies of the data, where *n* is the number of disks you have. A sufficiently paranoid person (which has included me on some critical servers) can use three-disk RAID1 to protect against the failure of any two disks.

Comment: @fafler:  In your performance comparison, did you compare the current RAID speed with the slowest drive?  That's the most you can expect from RAID1.

Comment: Your Samsung drive appears to be faster for random access, based on the specs.

Comment: @derobert Ignore what i said. I was somehow stupid enough to think "raid10" and ask a dumb question. Well, some performance hit is expected from software based raid configuration. Now, we will have to compare disk and bus specs to see where is the bottleneck. More hardware information will be helpful.

Comment: @nwildner At least with Linux mdraid, RAID10 doesn't require an even number of devices, either. 3-disk RAID10 works fine.

Comment: But that is a Non-standard Raid Level, and a corner case - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#LINUX-MD-RAID-10 - The same way EMC calls "raid 6" "raid 4" but the end of the day, it is all raid 5 with more or less parity disks, being 3 the lowest number of them...

Comment: If you can sleep with a single drive failure tolerance, you should go for RAID 10 and get a good 50-75% performance increase.

Comment: Thanks @JuliePelletier I didn't know RAID 10 could be used with a uneven number of drives. Not looking forward to taking everything down and making the switch, bit thanks non the less.

Comment: I run a 3 disk raid10 on my home system for the root filesystem and it works quite nicely.  By using the chunk size option to specify a large chunk size, you can get the sequential read performance of a 3 disk raid0 with better random read performance.  The rest of the disks are raid5 for bulk media storage.